# How to check the logs to see what process created a file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, filesystems, logs

The file dead.letter keeps appearing in my home folder. I want to know what process is responsible for this, but there is no information on the creator of a file in the file itself. However, I believe it should be possible for it's creation to recored in the log somewhere on the system.

Cheerio, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`dead.letter` is created by the `mail` utility when it is interrupted while sending an email.

You may avoid creating these by adding `set nosave` in `~/.mailrc`.